# Getting of prefill data in Room to spinner adapter

Tags: android, spinner, android-room

everybody! Today I was trying to solve the next problem: I've created room database for List of languages, prefill it with five ready object for different one's and then I was trying to transfer them into spinner adapter something like that:

Entity and DAO code for the `Language` object:

```
@Entity
public class Language {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "language")
    private String language;

    public Language(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public static Language[] populateData() {
        return new Language[]{new Language("English"), new Language("French"), new Language(
                "Spanish"), new Language("Russian"), new Language("Italian")};
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public long getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Dao
public interface LanguageDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM language")
    List<Language> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Language... languages);
}
```

Further I created database object with Singleton in the `AppDatabase` class like that:

```
@Database(entities = {Language.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
    public abstract LanguageDao languageDao();

    public synchronized static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = buildDatabase(context);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static AppDatabase buildDatabase(final Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "my-database")
                .addCallback(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onCreate(db);
                        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                getInstance(context).languageDao()
                                        .insertAll(Language.populateData());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }
}
```

As you can see I've inserted prefill data of language objects into the instance of Database. I know that's `allowMainThreadQueries()` method is not recommended here (just use it to simplify current training).

Further, I've created the following method which returns spinner object and put it into activity code:

```
private Spinner createLanguageSpinner(){
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.language_spinner);
    List<Language> languages = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).languageDao().getAll();
    List<String>languageStrings = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < languages.size(); i++){
        languageStrings.add(languages.get(i).getLanguage());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            languageStrings);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    return spinner;
}
```

My problem is here:

```
 List<Language> languages = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).languageDao().getAll();
```

I can't fill current List with predefined objects, which is resulted into empty spinner without options to choose. Could you tell where i'm getting wrong? I also would like to hear opinions about how can I simplify the creating of adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party, but in case if someone has this question too.

The problem is that you're trying to insert new objects without the PrimaryKey `id` value. As the result you're getting an empty table in the db.

You either should to set `id` value manually, e.g.:

```
@Entity
public class Language {

    ...

    public Language(long id, String language) {
        this.id = id; // or create method to generate a unique id as a PrimaryKey value must be unique
        this.language = language;
    }

    public static Language[] populateData() {
        return new Language[]{
                new Language(1, "English"),
                new Language(2, "French"),
                new Language(3, "Spanish"),
                new Language(4, "Russian"),
                new Language(5, "Italian")
        };
    }
}
```

Or use the `autoGenerate` property of the PrimaryKey to let SQLite generate the unique id:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long id;
```

See the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/PrimaryKey#autoGenerate()) for more information.

No other changes in your code are required.

---

**For the second question:**

> I also would like to hear opinions about how can I simplify the
>   creating of adapter

You can create a custom adapter for your spinner and pass a `List<Language>` to it directly:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Language> mItems;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Language> items) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position).getId();
    }

    // This is for the default ("idle") state of the spinner.
    // You can use a custom layout or use the default one.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
        }
        Language item = (Language) getItem(position);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(item.getTitle());
        return view;
    }

    // Drop down item view as stated in the method name.
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        }
        Language item = (Language) getItem(position);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(item.getTitle());
        return view;
    }
}
```

In your Activity:

```
List<Language> languages = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).languageDao().getAll();

Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, languages);
spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

See [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter) and [SpinnerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter) reference.

Or you can use `ArrayAdapter` and simply override `toString` method of your object to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list ([reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter)):

```
@Entity
public class Language {

    ...

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // A value you want to be displayed in the spinner item.
        return language;
    }
}
```

and in your Activity:

```
List<Language> languages = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).languageDao().getAll();

Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Pass your list as the third parameter. No need to convert it to List<String>
ArrayAdapter<Language> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, languages);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: According to the android design patterns you should use a repository and not call dao to populate your spinner, otherwise you could get an exception

Comment: @Zhar Of course. But this answer is based on the question, and to make it easier to follow I've used same methods as the OP did.

Comment: Does `R.layout.spinner_item` layout is the layout that spinner placed?